# Ignored key binding

Tags: key-bindings, init-file

I have a problem with following key binding:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-/") 'comment-or-uncomment-region)
```

Actually, it is ignored by Emacs so undo is executed instead.
I'm running Emacs in gui mode.

Comment: Do you have any minor-modes active such as `undo-tree`, which would override global bindings?  Type `M-x describe-key`  or `C-h k` and then your  keyboard shortcut and verify that the actual function being called is exactly `undo` or something else.   Also, check your `*Messages*` buffer for error messages after starting Emacs -- an error in the init file can cause Emacs to stop loading the file once it reaches that particular point.

Comment: It works for me. Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Yes, i have undo tree.

Comment: Not sure what's causing this, but maybe Emacs is not-so-subtly telling you to just use the `M-;` binding which does what you want by default already.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `describe-key`, I found that / is interprpeted as a `<kp-divide>`, so this keybind is working like a charm now. (thanks lawlist)

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<kp-divide>") 'comment-or-uncomment-region)
```